# How To Design an UI to support all the screens of iPhones and iPads

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, ui-design, adaptive-layout

I am working on a project in which I have to support all the iPhones screens like (iPhone4, iPhone 4S, iPhone 5S, iPhone 6, iPhone 6+) and iPads(iPad Mini, iPad Air, iPad Air 2, iPad 4, etc).

I was in a thought of using AutoLayout and AdaptiveLayout for the UI design. I learn that and try to apply in my project. I was more or less successful with the design with autolayout and adaptive layout, but, there is problem with resizing the textfield when the user edits it.

when the user tries to edit the textfield, we need to bring the textfield on top of the keyboard. so, that can be done in code,but, when we use the auto layout,  this code is not working now.
As per concept, when we use auto layout, we cannot resize the frame of the controls in view dynamically through code.

I am struck now?. Please help me with this guys. Thanks in Advance

Comment: I am also using auto layout but using following code (check my answer) we can change frames while user editing a text field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer this link for the answer. It will help us to bring the textfield on top even if we use AutoLayout.

https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding/blob/master/TPKeyboardAvoiding/TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView.m

Answer (score 0):

```
#pragma mark ----- Text field -----
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    // scroll up current text field
    [self animateTextField:textField up:YES withOffset:textField.frame.origin.y / 2];   
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

  [self animateTextField:textField up:NO withOffset:textField.frame.origin.y / 2];
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return true;
}
#pragma mark ---- Text field scroll Up -----
-(void)animateTextField:(UITextField*)textField up:(BOOL)up withOffset:(CGFloat)offset
{
    const int movementDistance = -offset;
    const float movementDuration = 0.4f;
    int movement = (up ? movementDistance : -movementDistance);
    [UIView beginAnimations: @"animateTextField" context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];
    self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

try this, it will help you

Comment: It will work without Autolayout. But, It will not work for autolayout Pravin

Comment: I am using auto layout but it working may b you miss something.